# Readyboost and JVM

Tags: java, memory

I am using a memory stick with the Readyboost property.

Java does not recognize the extra memory from the stick (if I set the Xmx to a value that exceeds the RAM value from the computer in order to use the stick memory, I get error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.)
```

Could you please give me a solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, [Readyboost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost) is a disk-caching feature (for persistent storage etc) - it's not related to physically addressable RAM / virtual address space.

Second, the -Xmx Java setting only sets the max *heap*. The JVM needs to use more than this value in total, due to the perm gen space and VM libraries / overheads. See here for further details:

[Java - Setting -Xmx etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450132/java-seems-to-ignore-xms-and-xmx-options/6450260#6450260)

Also, depending on what OS you're using (I'm assuming Windows 32-bit?), you can't assign more than a specified amount of memory (often 2 GiB) to a single process. Most 64-bit operating systems don't suffer from this limitation.

Comment: There is a switch on (32b) windows servers to allow processes to use 3G of ram, but this is not supported by sun/oracle's jvm,  JRocket does though (or used to when I last used it).   One thing to look out for is if you use NIO, this can require a lot of memory which restricts the amount available to the jvm heap.

Comment: @vickirk Exactly, any any native libraries etc loaded by the JVM sit on top of the Java heap too.