# Identify size of heap memory from a heap dump file?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, visualvm

I am using `-Xmx512m`, after out of memory error, I got a heap dump. On loading this heap dump to JAVA VisualVM heap size shown is more than 1 GB.

Not able to understand how heap size has grown to 1 GB when my `-Xmx` value is 512 MB.

[image: VisualVM Screen shot]

**EDIT**

I looked at the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450132/java-seems-to-ignore-xms-and-xmx-options) for which this question is marked as duplicate , I got one part of answer that JVM has Non Heap memory and other memory parts also ( given in below image )

[image: JVM Memory Parts]

But still one question is left. Is there any way I can identify size of only heap memory from a heap dump?

Comment: Are you looking just at the file size ?

Comment: @nos No I am looking at Total Bytes.

Comment: @nos I want to find out only heap size

Comment: We have edited this question , this is no more a duplicate question.

Comment: Can I get your heap dump to investigate what is going on?

Comment: @TomasHurka I can not provide dump , but you can take any dump for example.

Comment: No, it works fine in other cases.

Comment: To answer better late than never, no, you can’t calculate the actual heap size from a heap dump, because certain relevant information is missing, e.g. the actual pointer size for references or whether boolean arrays are stored using a byte or single bit per element. Further, the heap dump contains pure object data, whereas the occupation in a runtime heap is subject to address alignment and padding. So an analyzing tool has to do some guesswork about the relevant JVM properties and settings, to estimate the heap size. Speaking of JVisualVM and 2014, it likely didn’t know about CompressedOOPs…

Comment: @Holger after 4 year now I use XX:NativeMemoryTracking which gives memory information to certain extent(hotspot related memory usages). In JDK 8 it still does not track third party native code memory allocations, dont remember seeing any related update in latest JDK versions as well.

Comment: Well, but that native memory is outside the `-Xmx512m` anyway and also not included in the heap dump. So my previous comment only addressed the mismatch between VisualVM’s heap size calculations based on a heap dump and the JVM’s actual heap size, whereas native memory (or and kind of non-heap memory), is another issue.

Comment: @Holger you are right, I should have read my own question clearly. Recently I was trying to find out resident memory breakup (heap + non heap etc), for that I was using  XX:NativeMemoryTracking and my previous comment was related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Java heap will not be extended than the specified -Xmx. Heap allocation done at the JVM initialization so Heap extension is not possible  during the runtime. For more confirmation please add -verbose:gc jvm argument to collect GC occupancy  check the last cycle of the logs in order to verify the free space and allocated space of the application.

Comment: Please check my updated question at end of edit section.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/installingagent.html This tool help in  monitoring java process on run time . Hope this helps your requirement.

Answer (score -3):

I think this may help you

**https://www.eclipse.org/mat/**

I am not sure it can open just the heap memory from a heap dump but it is worth to try

**EDIT**

You may use JConsole
[image]

It shows what you are looking for

Comment: Using Jconsole i can identify heap usages of running java process , but i want to identify heap usages from a heap dump.