# How to limit JVM memory consumption?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, jvm, microservices

I developed a simple Spring Boot application (microservice you might say) and deployed with a simple `java -jar ... -Xmx 128M`. Yet, I can see using the `ps` command that the allocated memory for the process is actually `6237.26 Mb`.

Now, [I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450132/java-seems-to-ignore-xms-and-xmx-options) that and understood about the fact that `-Xmx` actually limits the process heap size but my question is:

1. Why does the JVM allocates so much RAM?
2. How can I limit it to a reasonable size?

**Update:**
Following the suggestion in the comment, I moved the `-Xmx128M` and now it's has allocated `4300MB` of RAM. Still a monster.

Comment: I think you need to put the `-Xmx<size>` before the `-jar`.

Comment: How big are your jars/how many do you have? Stuff like compiled code, class files, etc. all take up ram

Comment: Only 1 jar (42MB)